# Jquery - stick div to bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I found many plugins that allow me to stick navigation to the top of the page, or footer to the bottom of the page.

However, I have a div in the middle of the page, and would need to stick it at the bottom, until the user scrolls to it.

Is there any plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can use waypoints.js
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Then you can make a call like this:

```
$('.element').waypoint(function(direction){
    if(direction == 'down'){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
},{offset:'100%'});
```

Then for css you can do this

```
.sticky-container.active .stick-me {
    position:relative;
}

.sticky-container .stick-me {
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Just be aware that if you add the fixed css property to the element in my example marked ".element" then it may go a bit screwed up. It's best to make sure that the div ".element" is actually the wrapper to the element that you want the fixed css property to be assigned to.

Edit*: Sorry misread your question, thought you wanted it sticky when you scrolled to the element. I've updated the css above to suit you & your jsfiddle, please note the "offset" which I've set to 100%, this means it will add a class when in comes into the bottom of the viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/MNa7n/2/

Comment: Can you please be more specific, what CSS I need to add to the element?

Comment: Hmm, this almost works. I created jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/MNa7n/ .
I'd need to have the sticky displayed on page load, and as soon as it appears on the page, let it stay at it's original place (remove the active class as soon as I scroll to it)

Comment: Thanks! Last problem I have is I have some accordions on the page, and when I expand some, the change isn't reflected and the sticky element disappears too soon, before I scroll to it... Any fix for that?

Comment: Sure I'd be happy to help, might be better if you mark my answer as the best one so this is somewhat closed & then start a new question & link me to it (with another jsfiddle).

Comment: This is the new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058578/jquery-stick-element-on-bottom-of-the-page-until-scrolled-to-it-page-with-ac