# Jquery - Stick element on bottom of the page until scrolled to it - page with accordion

Tags: jquery, sticky-footer, jquery-waypoints

I have an element, that is sticked to the bottom of the page using `waypoints.js` and the following code:

```
  $('.sticky-container').waypoint(function (direction) {
      if (direction == 'down') {
          $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
  },{offset:'100%'});
```

This works fine, but I also have accordions on my page - when I open the accordion item, the page height changes, but the change isn't reflected in the waypoint script and the sticky element disappears too soon.

I created jsfiddle to explain better what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/SCr5L/3/

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hi There, Sorry for the late reply again. I did manage to have a look at this. I tried changing around your fiddle to "destroy" the waypoint on "click" of the call to action (then create a brand new waypoint), though unfortunately I got the same issue. Quite frankly I'm not too sure and I did spend a good 30 mins looking into it hah! I would suggest you move this issue to the waypoints.js github repo, create an issue there and the original developer (or other contributors) can get back to you!

https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, here's the Github issue: https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/issues/276

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing this, I got response from waypoints.js support:

> Bootstrap's hide.bs.collapse and show.bs.collapse fire at the
>   beginning of the collapse transitions. You want to use the events that
>   fire when the transition is complete, hidden.bs.collapse and
>   shown.bs.collapse:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.waypoints('refresh');
})
```

Works like a charm for me.